# Adding a mean line for each variable on a parallel coordinates plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using the iris dataset, I can make a parallel coordinates plot as follows.

```
library(GGally)
ggparcoord(data=iris,columns = (2:4),groupColumn = "Species")
```

I also want to plot the mean values of each variable for each flower species, on the same plot. How can I do this?

I have thought about making a new data frame with the mean values but that seems really inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think creating an extra dataframe with the means is required here, as there's no option to do this just using the arguments `ggparcoord` offers.

Preparing the dataframe with dplyr/tidyverse and plotting looks like:

```
libary(dplyr)

scaled_means <- iris %>%
  select(- Sepal.Length) %>%
  # Need to scale in the same as ggparcoord is doing
  mutate_at(vars(- Species), ~ scale(.)[, 1]) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize_all(mean) %>%
  pivot_longer(- Species, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value")

ggparcoord(data=iris,columns = (2:4),groupColumn = "Species") +
  geom_point(data = scaled_means, aes(x = variable, y = value, colour = Species),
             size = 3,
             inherit.aes = FALSE)
```

Result:

[image: plot with points added]

Comment: ~ scale(.)[, 1]

What does the 1 do here? Does this code always scale the means according to the scale method used in ggparcoord?

Comment: `scale()` in base R is a bit annoying, it returns its result as a matrix, so `[, 1]` is pulling that column out of the matrix and making it a vector. I wrote the code to match the default scaling in `ggparcoord`, but if you change the `ggparcoord` scaling option, you'll have to change the code.